# TypeScript - Mutability and inversion of Readonly<T>

Tags: typescript, immutability

Assume that I have the following mutable class:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public bar: any) { }
}
```

I can define `readonly` instances of this class like so:

```
const foo: Readonly<Foo> = new Foo(123);
foo.bar = 456; // error, can't reassign to bar because it's readonly.
```

What I'd like to be able to do is the inverse of this, where the class is immutable:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public readonly bar: any) { }
}
```

And then be able to make mutable versions like so:

```
const foo: Mutable<Foo> = new Foo(123);
foo.bar = 456;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can cast Foo to Mutable<Foo>, but it is not recommended since it is the contract of your Foo class... Why would you want to do it?

Comment: @htn because I believe that mutability should be opt-in, rather than opt-out. How would I cast to `Mutable<Foo>` (where presumably `Mutable<T>` is a type like `Readonly<T>`)?

Comment: You can define Mutable such as: `type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };`. However, it's dangerous because you can change the implementation of your class Foo later thinking that bar is readonly ==> It can break your app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use `-readonly` in type definition.

```js
type Mutable<T> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

const foo: Mutable<Foo> = new Foo(123);
foo.bar = 456;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrsAhgIwDYQDwBUB8UC8UA3gFBRQC0AThIgCYD2AdqiFANoAKUAlk1AGsIIBgDMoWALoAuCV0kBuEgF8lJAMapEAZ21QAYgwbEy5KAHMIwKMAjbgACgCUs5EfSJ+pM2ZrA4VPzAVHAQSj7KJKbk6sz2IerADFQOYHBoPOpQNPTMrFDIiFSyniBOxFCRkRpx1qJGsvBIaJiGDHiETBAA7gZGDgCMAEwAzE5K9QwAdIVUBFAALACsAGwTRlO29vOiiKjaYVAA9EdQRmDaADS81t08qKhQ6ohwB1CeUBBUVMlTJEA)

But remember it's only type definition, it doesn't change original logic.

```js
type Mutable<T> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

class Foo {
    get test(): boolean {
      return true;
    }

    constructor(public readonly bar: any) { }
}

const foo: Mutable<Foo> = new Foo(123);
foo.bar = 456;
foo.test = false; // oops, it will cause an error.
```